# Parameter Error, " Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1 Validation Rules

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, error

I created a validation rule, however, one field is giving me an error:  Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 1.

Here is the original validation rule:

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL(StageName,"3. Evaluation"), 

OR( 
ISPICKVAL( Do_you_send_your_sales_to_the_social_pub__c , "Not Answered"),
ISPICKVAL(Are_you_working_with_an_Agency_to_execut__c  , "Not Answered"),
ISPICKVAL(What_is_your_source_of_truth__c, "Not Answered"),
ISPICKVAL(Feed_Provider_details__c, "Not Answered"),
ISPICKVAL(Do_you_work_with_a_creative_agency_or_is__c, "Not Answered"),
ISPICKVAL(Feed_Update__c), "Not Answered"),
ISBLANK(How_are_you_optimizing_your_dynamic_ad_c__c),
ISPICKVAL(How_large_is_your_Product_Feed__c, "Not Answered"),
ISBLANK(What_percentage_if_any_are_dedicated_t__c ), 
ISBLANK(What_are_you_aiming_to_solve_with_a_part__c ), 
ISBLANK(What_areas_are_your_biggest_pain_points__c ), 
ISBLANK(What_is_your_primary_KPI_and_goals_Are__c ), 
ISBLANK(How_are_you_measuring_your_KPIs__c),
ISBLANK(How_are_you_optimizing_your_dynamic_ad_c__c))
```

I removed this field, ISPICKVAL(Feed_Update__c), "Not Answered"), and the rule works with no syntax error.  What is the correct format to not get this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your other ISPICKVALs are correct, you just need

```
ISPICKVAL(Feed_Update__c, "Not Answered"),
```

You had a spurious paren:

```
ISPICKVAL(Feed_Update__c), "Not Answered"),
                        ^
                        ^
```